# How to structure Crypto library

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, cryptography

I'm trying to write my own Crypto library in C++, but I'm having some trouble with the OOP-side of things.

I'm trying to structure my library in a way that allows optimal modularity and reusability, while still being easy-to-use for anyone that, well, uses the library.

I've already implemented AES (128, 192 and 256) and I'm able to correctly encrypt and decrypt data (I wrote some unit tests that use NIST's ECB test vectors)

Right now I'm trying to get AES to work in a chained matter. (So Proper ECB, CBC, CFB, OFB, ...)

I'm at a loss on how to structure my library in a way that makes it easy-to-use for an "end-user" (most likely just me in other projects).

Right now, this is how I have it set up:

I have a `CipherFactory` class that has a static method `createBlockCipher`, this method takes in the name of a block cipher as a string and returns a `BlockCipher` object that can be used for encryption and decryption of single blocks.

I have a `BlockCipher` class that is basically a super-class to all block ciphers I implement (Right now just AES, I will probably add some more along the way). The `BlockCipher` class provides some getters for getting blocksize,  keysize and the algorithm's name. It also has virtual encryption and decryption methods that throw a `NotImplemented` exception when called, to prevent someone from trying to encrypt anything with this fictious super-class.

Then I have an `AES` class that inherits from the `BlockCipher` class and implements its encryption and decryption methods.

I guess what I'm looking for is some UML class-diagrams, design patterns or general advice that allows me to implement chaining modes in an elegant way.

I've already had a look at Crypto++ but their documentation and code looks rather cryptic to me (How ironic!).

(For those of you that aren't that knowledgable in the crypto department but are good with OOAD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Common_modes)

*Disclaimer: I know that DIY-crypto is a bad idea most (if not all) of the time, I'm not planning on encrypting anything serious with it, this is just a personal project.*

Comment: How can anyone get hold of a base `BlockCipher` object if you're creating them through a factory? Can't you just not give them out?

Comment: You have a very good point. I figured I'd put the methods in there "just in case". I also figured, I'd still put them in there in case somehow, a `BlockCipher` object gets default-constructed. (Basically, I'm just trying to prevent myself from making things worse by using these bogus objects) I also have a bunch of `if-else if-else if-...` statement in the factory for identifying the algorithm's name. When the statements fall through to the last possibilty (A regular `else`) I return a BlockCipher object, I guess I should throw an exception instead?

Comment: The big issue with the existing implementations is the lack of documentation, especially the defaults. For a reasonably good example see [RNCryptor-Spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec). Note the version, optional password extension, IV handling and authentication. It would be good to have password extension, IV handling and authentication as optional so the library can be used with existing implementations. CBC, ECB and CTR are essential, GCM is necessary going forward but is not easy to implement the math.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a variation on the Decorator Design Pattern.

You could make each cypher class's constructor take an instance of a `const BlockCipher&` as an argument, and have the instance being constructed store it as the next cypher in the chain.

The `CipherFactory` could then have a `CreateBlockCypherChain()` method that takes an array of string names and returns a chain constructed from those cyphers.